# open a new activity in original activity and finish original one

Tags: android

I am new to Android application development. I tried to create a new activity when a ListView which triggers an action when an item is clicked.

During testing, my code was working. But I am a little bit confused on whether I should use finish() to close the current activity. Which one is better? From performance or resource usage point of view?

Below is some of my code :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bank_name);
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg)   {

                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      if (position == 0) {
                          return_to_config(view);
                      }


                }
    });


public void return_to_config(View view){
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfigActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       *this.finish();*
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to worry about resource or performance in this situation. You should be most concerned on the functionality that you want and your users expect.

If they are clicking a list item and open up say a detailed `Activity` for that list item then they press the back button then they probably expect to return to that list. If you call `finish()` then the user will return to the `Activity` before this one or if there are no others then they will exit the app. Is that what you want?

So with what little I know about your app I would say remove `finish()`

```
public void return_to_config(View view){
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfigActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

}

But if the user doesn't expect to return here when pressing "Back" button then keep it in there

Comment: thanks, you get my intention. But actually after back button is clicked, I will fill in something in my old listview. So for the old listview activity, do I need to create it again with updated contents? Or I can return to the old one and update the corresponding item? Which one is better ?

Comment: You will just need to let the `Adapter` know that the list has changed with `setAdapter()` or `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the original `ListView`. But unless you have a specific reason, there is no need to destroy the `Activity` and create a new one

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, you can override the onPause() and write finish() over there. It is more efficient

Comment: Have anything to back up "more efficient"? I'm not sure I see how that could be.

Comment: do you mean once a new activity is opened, the old one will turn to onPause(), then generally we write our finish() in there to make it more smooth?

Comment: Geobits: "More efficient" points to the fact that once the new activity is started then our activity would definitely call onPause, thus we are sure that finish() would be called once the new activity is spawned